Preserve capitalization of the input text when copy/pasting from the output PDF
I noticed that, if I compile my document with XeLaTeX, copy-pasting text in small capitals from the PDF results in uppercase text. To the contrary, LuaLaTeX, preserves the capitalization of the input text in the generated PDF, so if you have, say, \textsc{Hello} as input, copy-pasting it will result in Hello instead of HELLO.
This seems to be related to the choice of font. I am using Gentium Plus, which (apparently) supports small caps. If I do not select this font, the problem disappears.
Minimal example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Hello}
\end{document}


@DavidCarlisle Thank you, I updated the question.

@DavidCarlisle I get small caps with lualatex, and I get different copy & paste and in the PDF there are clearly different ToUnicode values assigned.

Note that small caps are not capital letters but a font style. They are small letters that look like small capital letters. Since it is a style of a font, it should be correct that you get small letters if you copy small caps. It would be wrong if you would get capital letters at least in my opinion. You should, however, get capital letters if you used a command such as \MakeUppercase which changes capitalisation (but does not change the style of the font).
